# Model instancing and transforming

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Let's say I wanted to load 100 individual models (components of a bigger whole) into the viewer and have 10 instances of each. Those 1000 instances would be positioned, rotated and scaled according to some rules to form the final model view.

I know how to load multiple models with the viewer, so my questions are:

1) Does loading so many models into the viewer make any sense? The models would be quite small in size.

2) Should it be done normally with viewer3d.start and viewer3d.load? How does the instancing work, will I run into trouble with such a large number of models?
Will I have 1000 load calls or can the instancing be done in some other way?

3) How do I transform an entire model? I know how to transform fragments of a model. In case of transforming the whole model do I transform all its fragments or is there a hierarchy so I can just transform a "root fragment"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Q1 and Q2: aggregating multiple models in one scene is a common use case, however for large number of models you could start hitting performance limits as I'm afraid the viewer has no support for internal sharing of geometry data between models.

Regarding Q3: as far as I know, there's no way to change the transform of an already loaded model. There's something called "placement transform" that *might* be configurable before loading a model, but I think it's just transforming each fragment individually under the hood. I will double-check with the dev team.

Comment: Btw. the dev. team confirmed my answer to Q3: there's no way to transform the entire model as a single entity. You can transform all fragments of the model, or pass in the "placement transform" ([tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multimodel-search-support-forge-viewer-v40)) when loading the model which will do the same thing under the hood.